# How to use both .sort and .toSet methods together in Flutter Dart

Tags: flutter, list, dart, sorting, methods

List colour= ["peach","red","yellow","green","black"];

//How to use both .sort and .toSet methods together in Flutter Dart.

Comment: To what end?  With that list, what result do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Sort method return type void so you can not use .toSet Method together.
But after applying sort you can use .toSet method it works as you expected

Try this

```
List colour= ["peach","red","yellow","green","black"]; 
colour.sort((a, b) => a.length.compareTo(b.length));   
colour.toSet().toList();
```

Comment: Dose this language have an idea of a sorted set?

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension:

```
extension SortEX on List {
  List sortAndSet() {
    sort();
    return toSet().toList();
  }
}
```

the result you get :

```
//[black, green, peach, red, yellow]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the `List` first, then `toSet()`

```
List colour= ["peach","red","yellow","green","black", "black"];

colour.sort();
var res = colour.toSet();
print(res); //{black, green, peach, red, yellow}
```